# Elasticsearch without Maven

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

Recently I have begun working on a Java Spring project that does not use Maven and I need to build elasticsearch functionality into the program but I cannot find any information about how to import elasticsearch without the use of Maven.

Has anyone ever had to do something similar?

Is it maybe possible to just use Maven on this one part of the project?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: are u using any build system? e.g. maven gradle ant. How are u packaging the project? using ide? then which ide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven just provide you a way to manage your dependencies. So, if you manage your dependencies in directly downloading JARs, you just have to download all the dependencies you needs and include them in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

As @Camille Gerin-Roze said , all you need is to download the ElasticSearch dependencies and add them to the classpath.

A place to start is :

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.3.5
```

And using the "Download Jar" link

[image]

If you scroll down and read the part that says **"Compile Dependencies (32)"** , it will tell you what other dependencies you need to download manually and add to the class path.

Please note that each of these dependencies may or may not have co dependencies that you may need to download and add to the classpath as well.

[image]